# Mqtt-Integration in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mqtt

i try to integrate mqtt in my Spring Boot Java Project.

My depdency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mqtt</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I created a Java-Class named MqttClient.
Here i try this:

```
IMqttClient publisher = new org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient("pfad", publisherId);
```

I get a Error here: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient

Error:Unhandled exception: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException

Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Can you post the full error message? As that probably has a hint of what has gone wrong.

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/libraries-server

Comment: https://medium.com/@harkesh.kumar/mqtt-integration-with-spring-boot-fd762f258536

Answer (score 0):

Can't figure out what is the problem? I did solve the same problem in following fashion. See if it works for you. I have a mqtt gateway class defined as below.

```
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "mqttPromiseOutboundChannel")
public interface MqttPromiseGateway {

    void sendToMqtt(String data);
}
```

When I want to send a message to Mqtt, I autowire the defined gateway class.

```
@Autowired
private MqttPromiseGateway mqttPromiseGateway;
```

Now I can send a message over that Mqtt channel using that gateway.

```
 mqttPromiseGateway.sendToMqtt(content);
```

We also define a service for MqttProducer.

```
@Service
public class DemoMqttProducer {

    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setServerURIs(new String[] { "tcp://localhost:1883" });
        options.setUserName("myusername");
        options.setPassword("mypassword#".toCharArray());
        factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
        return factory;
    }


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttPromiseOutboundChannel")
    public MessageHandler mqttPromiseOutbound() {
        MqttPahoMessageHandler messageHandler =
                new MqttPahoMessageHandler("testClient", mqttClientFactory());
        messageHandler.setAsync(true);
        messageHandler.setDefaultTopic("Promise");
        return messageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttOutboundChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttPromiseOutboundChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound())
                .transform(p -> p + ", received from MQTT")
                .handle(logger())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProducerSupport mqttInbound() {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("siSampleConsumer",
                mqttClientFactory(), "Promise");
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(1);
        return adapter;
    }    

}
```

The method mqttInflow will get the incoming message and send it to logger. If you want to handle it differently, you need to change that method.